# Python nested json object being serialize as str

Tags: python, json, simplejson

Hi I have made a custom JSONEncoder and happened to run into this issue. When I use the `dumps` function of simplejson the nested object gets serialize as a string. For example I use this:

```
simplejson.dumps({'lat': obj.lat, 'lon': obj.lon})
```

And get this:

```
{
website: "http://something.org",
location: "{"lat": 12.140158037163658, "lon": -86.24754807669069}"
}
```

If you see location object is with double quotes is there a way I can specify location object to be dump properly as a JSON object (without the double quotes).

**Edit**

```
class jsonEncoder(simplejson.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        isinstance(obj, db.GeoPt):
            return simplejson.dumps({'lat': obj.lat, 'lon': obj.lon})

        else:
            return simplejson.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Comment: The quotes are not optional in JSON (unlike JavaScript object literals). You have to *add* quotes for your example to be proper JSON.

Comment: Looks like that the problem resides in your JSONEncoder implementation. You may want to add your implementation here to get better help.

Comment: @Necronet : alternatively you could pass dict with lat, lon argument to  JsonEncoder .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't return a string from default() when obj is a db.GeoPt.  Instead, return the dict with keys 'lat' and 'lon', and let the JSON library serialize the dict.

Try this:

```
class jsonEncoder(simplejson.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, db.GeoPt):
            return {'lat': obj.lat, 'lon': obj.lon}
        else:
            return simplejson.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```